# SingleOrDefault() when the sequence contains the default value

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have stumbled upon an interesting scenario, which I couldn't find a solution to. Suppose I have to find the majorant in a sequence (the number that occurs at least `n / 2 + 1` times, where `n` is the size of the sequence). This is my implementation:

```
public static int FindMajorant(IList<int> numbers)
{
    return numbers
        .GroupBy(x => x)
        .Where(g => g.Count() >= numbers.Count / 2 + 1)
        .Select(g => g.Key)
        .SingleOrDefault();
}
```

I'm using `SingleOrDefault()`, which returns the element if it's found in the sequence or the default value for the type: in this case, it will return `0` as it's the default value for an `int`. For example, my method returns `3` for the following sequence:

```
List<int> sampleNumbers = new List<int>() { 2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 4, 3, 3 };
```

which is the expected behaviour.

However, what happens if the majorant in the sequence is zero (`0`)? It would return 0, but that way, how could I determine whether it's the zero from `SingleOrDefault()` as a default value, or the majorant? Perhaps, I could use `Single()`, but that would throw an exception which is pretty much incorrent. I could also catch this exception, but this seems a bad practice to me. So my question is, what's the preferred way to handle this situation?

Comment: Note that you can pull `numbers.Count / 2 + 1` out of the query and into a variable to avoid recalculating it for every single group.

Comment: @Servy isn't `Count` a property of `IList<T>` so it's not actually being calculated?

Comment: @MichaelMcGriff He is referring to the expression as a whole.

Comment: @MichaelMcGriff You're still dividing it by 2 and adding one over and over.  You're correct that any sensible `IList` implementation won't have io iterate the collection to get a count.

Comment: @Servy I thought the compiler might be smart enough to know that `number.Count / 2 + 1` wouldn't change during the process and not have to recalculate it each time.  Thanks for the information.

Comment: @MichaelMcGriff The compiler is smart enough to know that `number.Count` *can* change between invocations of that delegate, which is why it *can't* avoid recalculating it each time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use a nullable value where `null` indicates that there is no majorant, rather than using "0" to mean that.  And conveniently enough, the default value of `int?` is `null`, so the only change needed to your code is to get a sequence of nullable ints before calling `SingleOrDefault`.

```
public static int? FindMajorant(IList<int> numbers)
{
    return numbers
        .GroupBy(x => x)
        .Where(g => g.Count() >= numbers.Count / 2 + 1)
        .Select(g => (int?)g.Key)
        .SingleOrDefault();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could project the result in to a typed object say `MajorantResult` thus then returning null:

```
    public static MajorantResult FindMajorant(IList<int> numbers)
    {
        return numbers
            .GroupBy(x => x)
            .Where(g => g.Count() >= numbers.Count/2 + 1)
            .Select(g => new MajorantResult(g.Key))
            .SingleOrDefault();
    }

    public class MajorantResult
    {
        public int Key { get; }

        public MajorantResult(int key)
        {
            this.Key = key;
        }
    }
```